# Approximating number of integers with smallest prime factor above a given number?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I am trying to approximate the number of integers less than $x$ that have no prime factors less than $B$.  Is such an approximation known? If so, how good is it?

Note that this should not be confused with approximating $x - \Psi(x, B)$, since that would approximate the numbers less than $x$ that have at least one prime factor greater than or equal to $B$.

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking about smooth numbers, in which case, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number

Comment: See my note: it is not so simple as subtracting from x the number of B-smooth numbers less than x.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: How many primes are there in between B and X ? How many of their products are less then X ? For the first question, see [prime-counting function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) $\pi(n)\simeq\dfrac n{\ln n}$ . For the second, $p_k^2\in[B^2,x]$ would be a necessary, though insufficient, first condition.

Comment: Did you mean to put $=$ there?

Comment: No. I meant that, apart from the actual primes in between B and X, the smallest composites are of the form $p_jp_k$, with both $p_j$ and $p_k$ in between B and X. But that first prime $\ge B$ also has to be $\le\sqrt x$ in order for such composites to even exist...

Comment: I meant the $\pi(n)=n/\ln n$ statement.

Comment: Oh! Sorry. :-) I've fixed it now.

Comment: I am not sure how to fully and correctly express this in mathematical notation, but is the solution: $(\pi(x)-\pi(B)) + (\pi(x^{\frac{1}{2}})-\pi(B))^2 + (\pi(x^{\frac{1}{3}})-\pi(B))^3 + ...$ until the first term in which $\pi(x^{\frac{1}{i}})-\pi(B)$ is negative?

Comment: @Gnosis_X: My advice? Run a computer program. If you have a theory, test it. Don't be afraid. See if the facts support it. If the data contradicts it, check the code. If no errors in implementation are found, re-think the formula. (To answer your question: Yes, it does look like what I had in mind, BUT don't just take my word for it, verify it, because I've been wrong many times in the past).